# SharePoint 2013 navigation permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I have setup a metadata navigation. But now i only want sites to be visible for users that are members on this sites. Security triming does not works with metadata navigation, i was thinking some solution with jsom?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a script to determine the presence of a user in the group:

```
function isCurrentUserInGroup(groupName, functionUserInGroup, functionUserNotInGroup, functionGroupNotFound, functionOnError) { 
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    //Get info of current user 
    var currentUser = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser(); 
    ctx.load(currentUser, 'Id', 'LoginName'); 
    //Retrieve all site groups 
    var groups = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups(); 
    ctx.load(groups); 

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) { 
        //See whether the group exists 
        var groupFound = false; 
        var groupEnumerator = groups.getEnumerator(); 
        while (groupEnumerator.moveNext() && !groupFound) { 
            var group = groupEnumerator.get_current(); 
            if (group.get_title() == groupName) { 
                //Found the group, now try to load users of this group 
                groupFound = true; 
                var users = group.get_users(); 
                ctx.load(users); 
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) { 
                    //See whether the user exists 
                    var userFound = false; 
                    var userEnumerator = users.getEnumerator(); 
                    while (userEnumerator.moveNext() && !userFound) { 
                        var user = userEnumerator.get_current(); 
                        if (user.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) { 
                            //User exists in the group 
                            userFound = true; 

                            if (functionUserInGroup != null) 
                                functionUserInGroup(); 
                        } 
                    } 

                    //User doesn't exist in the group 
                    if (!userFound && (functionUserNotInGroup != null)) 
                        functionUserNotInGroup(); 

                }, function (sender, args) { 
                    if (functionOnError != null) 
                        functionOnError(sender, args); 

                }); 
            } 
        } 

        //Group doesn't exist 
        if (!groupFound && (functionGroupNotFound != null)) 
            functionGroupNotFound(); 

    }, function (sender, args) { 
        if (functionOnError != null) 
            functionOnError(sender, args); 

    }) 

}
```

Example of using:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { 
    isCurrentUserInGroup('rtCoordinators', 
        function () { 
            alert('User is in the group.'); 
            var field = new Igotta.StandartListFormsUtility.SPFieldText('Title');
            field.hide();
        }, 
        function () { 

        }, 
        function () { 
            alert('Group does NOT exist.'); 
        }, 
        function (sender, args) { 
            alert('Request failed.' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
        }); 
    }, "sp.js");
```

Now you have information about user group.
Now add the logic to hide menu items

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try it with modifying my changes